# Import Excel sheet to access table with different column names but same data type.

Tags: excel, ms-access, import

Folks,

I am learning access, but have sufficient experince with .net. The below utility has to be developed in access.

I want to upload/import data from an excel sheet to an access table which does not have same column names. I cannot change the name of the columns in access table as the table is kind of template for some other imports from excel sheet.

Can it be done at all. If yes please share a way that can be done.

What all options do I have in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it two steps:

1) Import the Excel sheet into Access with whatever table name you want.

2) Create an append query that then takes each field from your Excel-generated table and maps it to the relevant field in the target Access table.

This will help particularly if you are doing this process regularly